# Currying a function with a variable in J

Tags: currying, j

I can create a function that multiplies by `2` with `2&\*`, and indeed `20 = (2&\*)10`

What I want to do is create a factory-function that makes these to order.

So, I want a monad f s.t. `( f y ) x == (y * x )`

whilst `(\*& 2) 3` works `((\*&) 2) 3` doesn't, so trying explicitly:

`(3 : 'y&*') 2` produces a syntax error.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: You may want to be careful about using parentheses to imply multiplication. J doesn't do this; it only uses parentheses as punctuation to separate the components of a sentence.

Comment: oops -- stackoverflow removed the "*" operator as I didn't escape it.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A verb that creates a verb is actually an adverb<sup>1</sup> in J:

```
f =: 1 : 'm&*'
2 f
2&*

(2 f) 5
10

(i.10)f 5
0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
```

or tacitly:

```
f =: &*
2 f
2&*
```

`h =: 3 :'...'` won't work because that produces a verb and then `h y` wants to be a noun.

`g =: 4 :'x&* y'` is fine and equivalent to `f`.

<sup>[1]: or a conjunction</sup>